# Guidewire batch job processing using Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, batch-processing, gatling, guidewire

How can I run the Guidewire batch job scenarios using Gatling. Mainly want to create a scala script to run the batch job in gatling

Answer (score 0):

In webservice catalogue of your center check the MaintenanceToolsAPI, there are few exposed operations:

- getValidBatchProcessNames - will give you batch process names
- startBatchProcess - for batch process without arguments
- startBatchProcessWithArguments - for running batch process with arguments

Guidewire also did a batchrunner accelerator where they use this API and expose something a bit more consistent/usable this is available in marketplace.

In the end you should be fine with just calling the MaintenanceToolsAPI SOAP webservice from your scala scripts. What you will probably have to figure is the polling for the state of batch process, which is main feature of batchrunner accelerator.